# How can to set column field with related column field in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have the following two sql tables:

[image]

The GlassesID Column in Glasses table is the primery key defined as auto Increaseble.
The GlassesColor table has GlassesID(not auto Increaseble) colomn that defined as Foreign Key.

When Glasses table get a record (from stored procedure)GlassesID automatecly get value. 
The GlassesColor.GlassesID column must be set with value from Glasses.GlassesID Column.
My question is how can i implement this? i,e... How can i set column field with related column field in another table?

Comment: Try to add a trigger to table Glasses, whitch inserts a row into GlassesColor after every insert.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using (SQL Server (which based on the diagram it looks like), MySQL, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after you insert a record into Glasses table, get the ID from Glasses table

```
declare @GlassesID as int
select @GlassesID = scope_identity();
```

Then you can use @GlassesID to insert into GlassesColor table.

```
insert GlassesColor(GlassesID, .....)
values(@GlassesID, .....);
```

Comment: Eric,what is scope_identity()?

Comment: scope_identity() is a built-in function available in mssql. it returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column within the same scope. There is another one @@Identity but it's not limited to a specific scope; so @@Identity could return an identity from a trigger resulted from another insert. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx